# How to check if a user is in a role in Asp.Net Core Identity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity

I've an app that will have multiples level of organization, and for each level, there will be rights(admin-reader-...).

I want to create(and maintain) a list of roles for each user, but it means that a lot of those roles name will be dynamic, like `{id-of-the-organization]-admin`.

Therefore, I cannot just do the usual `Authorize`:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, PowerUser")]
public class ControlAllPanelController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult SetTime() =>
        Content("Administrator || PowerUser");

    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public IActionResult ShutDown() =>
        Content("Administrator only");
}
```

I would like to have something like

```
public class ControlAllPanelController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult SetTime(Guid organizationId) {
        someService.Authorize(organizationId+"-SetTime");//Throw exception or return boolean
        //... rest of my logic
    }
}
```

Not sure how to achieve this? I've seen example of this with the `IAuthorize` service, but this was requiring to provide policies name, which I don't have for this case(Or maybe there is one by default but I don't know its name. `

I've seen that the `ClaimsPrincipal` has a `IsInRole`, but I'm not totally sure it get the latest information from Asp.Net Core Identity Framwork(from the user manager) (only what is stored inside the token?)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpContext` to look at the claims in the JWT.

I have recently been working with authorizations in .NET API and this is what I done:

```
var identity = this.HttpContext.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault();
var role = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "role").Value;
                    
if (role != "Admin")
{
    return Unauthorized("You don't have to correct permissons to do this.");
}
```

So I'm getting the Identity details, then searching the claims for the `role` claim.

As a side note, Im using this in a controller inheriting from `ControllerBase` so I believe `HttpContext` is a property of this class so no need to inject it if you're using this. Else, you'd probably have to use it via DI, but should all work the same.

Comment: IsInRole basically iterates over the claim, so I think it would be a better fit. But what if the user had some changes in its user permissions since the JWT generation? My understanding is that claims in the JWT should only be used client side to know what are the allowed rights, but it's insecure to use them on the server to validate rights

Comment: Hmmm, yeah i'm not sure. In my method I am using the `Authorize` annotation with the Roles parameter, then once they have passed that, if they try and create an admin user but don't have the right permissions then they get unauthorized like the code above. So maybe you can add back in the `Authorize` annotation, then create a a global `Set-Time` role, then do the checks inside the method? Alternatively, maybe store the userId in a claim, then fetch it from the userManager, that way you will see the most up to date roles from the retrieved user.

Comment: But still, JWT token are typically generated every 5-15 minutes, and you might have some changes. Having the Authorize will ensure that you have an authentified user, but if you check the claims after, I'm not sure that it prevents you from a user rights changes.